# Interpolate raster value using Python

Tags: python, raster, point, code-review, value-extraction

I'm new in coding.
I have a shapefile (points) and 15 raster files
My purpose is get the values from all raster to point (each point will get value from 2 or 3 nearest cell baseed on distance of the point to cell).
I already built code for that and it is working but it takes so much time for running.

Could you optimize the code to make it run faster?

```
import os
import rioxarray as rxr
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

### definition extract_raster:
def extract_raster(points_gdf, raster_xarray):
    extracted_values = []
    for _, point in points_gdf.iterrows():
        value = raster_xarray.interp(x=point.geometry.x, y=point.geometry.y)
        extracted_values.append(value.values)
    
    column_name = 'raw'
    points_gdf[column_name] = extracted_values
    points_gdf[column_name] = points_gdf[column_name].astype(float)
    return points_gdf
# import data

lidar_chm_path = os.path.join(r"D:\CHM\CHM.tif")
lidar_chm_xr = rxr.open_rasterio(lidar_chm_path, masked=True).squeeze()
NFI_path = os.path.join("SHP_file", "Final_NFI.shp")
NFI_data = gpd.read_file(NFI_path)


##CHM
extract_raster(NFI_data, lidar_chm_xr)
NFI_data.rename(columns={'raw': 'CHM'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: How many points are there?

Comment: Also how large are your raster files? The dimension and resolution of the  rasters.

Comment: For code review there is the [codereview.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I have around 4000 points. The raster size = 20810x18620 pixel, with resolution = 30x30m.